# Send NSArray Via AirDrop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, serialization, airdrop

I have an `NSMutableArray` `self.certificates`

This array is made up of saved strings  and core data.  I want to send this through AirDrop.  I have checked out `serialization` and and im trying to send it with the folowing

```
- (void)send{

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.certificates options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Electrical Certificates List:\n%@", jsonString);


UIActivityViewController *activityCtr = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[jsonString]
                                                                          applicationActivities:nil];

NSMutableArray *excludedActivities = [self iOSActivities].mutableCopy;
[excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];
[excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToFlickr];
[excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
[excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
[activityCtr setExcludedActivityTypes:excludedActivities];

[self presentViewController:activityCtr
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
}
```

This gives me the following error
    `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Certificate)'`

I have converted to data to a string so not sure what im missing here

Ive researched [NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337419/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-invalid-type-in-json-write-nsdate) and [How to send NSArray to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175811/how-to-send-nsarray-to-web-service)

Answer (score 4):

The exception is thrown by `JSONSerialization`, before the array is converted to data.

To share a custom data type, you'll want to implement `NSCoding` and `UIActivityItemSource` on your model object:

```
@interface CertificateGroup : NSObject <NSCoding, UIActivityItemSource>

@property(copy, nonatomic) NSArray *certificates;

@end

@implementation CertificateGroup

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    // Save all your custom properties
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.certificates forKey:@"certificates"]l
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Read back properties
        self.certificates = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"certificates"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    //Let the activity view controller know NSData is being sent by passing this placeholder.
    return [NSData data];
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    //Serialize this object for sending. NSCoding protocol must be implemented for the serialization to occur.
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return @"com.mycompany.myapp.certificates";
}

@end
```

Then, when you create your activity view controller:

```
CertificatesGroup *group = [CertificatesGroup new];
group.certificates = self.certificates;
UIActivityViewController *activityCtr = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[group]
                                                                          applicationActivities:nil];
...
```

You're app delegate should implement `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and decode the incoming certificates.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
     NSData *groupData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     CertificatesGroup *group = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:groupData];
     NSLog(@"%@", group.certificates);
     return YES;
}
```

For more info, see Apple's [AirDropSample](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013842-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) project, especially `APLProfile.h`/`.m`, `APLProfileViewController.h`/`.m` and `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that gives me a nil string for `archivedString`

Comment: Ah, it's probably not a valid string. You might be able to pass the `NSData` object directly to the activity view controller. I assume, however, that you want to be able to open this data in your app on the receiving device, then decode it?

Comment: Yes thats its, the NSMutable array populates a table view, i want to send this to another device and receive an decode it.  Just a way to manually keep devices in sync, tried iCloud but cant seem to get that functioning at all!

Comment: Are your certificates custom objects, or provided by the framework?

Comment: They are Custom objects

Comment: Updated my answer. You should probably read through that whole AirDropSample example - it will help a lot with understanding how AirDrop works.

Comment: Thnak you very much for providing such a detailed answer - plus 1, ive got the air drop sample code an have been studying it.  Just one more  question `self.certificates = [aDecoder objectForKey:@"certificates"];` gives me `no visibel@ interface error NSCoder declares the object`

Comment: Sorry, should be `decodeObjectForKey:`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks for that, and should I return self in that method? or NSData? Presumably its NSData in the delegate method you provided?

Comment: Which delegate method?

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {` what should I be returning here? Im retuning self in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {` Correct?

Comment: You should return a `BOOL` indicating whether the request was handled successfully in app delegate method, and `self` in the init method.